# PHP tag is closing with code in query $db->

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Forgive me, as I've not worked in php for years. I'm picking up some old code to get working again and I'm having a strange issue.

I'm writing in php with wordpress. As I am editing the code, I've noticed the php tag is closing after the following:

```
<?php
$databaseHost = "Localhost";
$databaseName = "testDB";
$databaseUser = "TESTUSER";
$databasePassword = "TESTPASS";

$coin_id = (isset($_POST['coin_id'])) ? $_POST['coin_id'] : '';

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $databaseHost . ';dbname=' . $databaseName . ';charset=utf8', $databaseUser, $databasePassword);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $request = "SELECT
    _7UR_participants_database.city,
            _7UR_participants_database.state,
            _7UR_participants_database.country,
            _7UR_participants_database.zip,
            _7UR_participants_database.coin_id,
            FROM _7UR_participants_database GROUP BY _7UR_participants_database.coin_id ASC";           
$stmt = $db->query($request);
$item_info = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage(); 
    exit;
} // Try / catch end
?>
```

Everything after that > following $db- is not included in the php. The php tag is closing with that last >. Do I need to escape the character or something of that nature?

Comment: I'm not really getting the issue. Are you saying that `$db->` closes the PHP context? It won't. Then there's something else it complains about. However, if you just have `$db->` alone without defining a method or property, you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be closing the tag as you mention. There is more after the $db->. I omitted it for brevity but I'll edit it in as I see how that can be confusing.

Comment: No, it doesn't close the php context there. Please show us more context (the code after) and why you think it gets closed.

Comment: I've edited the code. Everything beyond the > in question appears in plain text on the web page. To clarify - setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); and beyond is showing up on the webpage, as if it's closed the php tag.

Comment: If you see the code after, then right click on the page and choose "View source". I'll bet you then see the PHP code before it as well. Basically, your PHP code doesn't get executed at all. The browser sees `<?` as an opening HTML element and the first `>` as closing that HTML element. How did you open the file? Through a web server with PHP support (with a proper http:// address) or did you just double clicked on the file in your file system?

Comment: This is on a hosted website - I thought it should be interpreting the php as it's wordpress. Now that you say that - I see the source is commenting out the php tags. Any Idea how or why that is happening? The > is closing the html comment.

Comment: _"I thought it should be interpreting the php as it's wordpress"_ - Wordpress is just an application written in PHP. To the server, "wordpress" doesn't mean anything. The server needs to have PHP support, or you won't be able to run PHP on it. Check your host. Btw, does the file have the extension `.php`? If not, then that could be the issue.

Comment: It's hosted by a wordpress  recommendation. It is guaranteed to support it. The page in question is a page added with wordpress - in a database. I suppose that is probably the problem, it's not a .php file. Now I need to figure out how to add custom pages to a wordpress page I think.

Comment: If you added that code in a content block for a post in WP, then no, it won't work. Wordpress just outputs the contents, it doesn't get executed as PHP.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you. my first foray into wp and I haven't built anything in years.

Comment: This isn't WP specific. If you echo a string containing PHP code with PHP, that won't be executed as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

since your formatting is hard to undertand i rewrite it on my liking that it "migth" actually works

```
 $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDB;charset=utf8mb4";  // most cool kids use charset=utf8mb4 
        $options = [
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
        ];
        try {
          $dbh = new PDO($dsn, "TESTUSER", "TESTPASS", $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          error_log($e->getMessage());
          echo ("Error Code: " . $e->getCode() . "<br>"); // never use echo on public release build it would leak your database credential this is optional great for troubleshooting 
          echo ("Error Message: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>");
          exit('Something weird happened');//
        }
       $request = $dbh->prepare("SELECT
        _7UR_participants_database.city,
                _7UR_participants_database.state,
                _7UR_participants_database.country,
                _7UR_participants_database.zip,
                _7UR_participants_database.coin_id,
                FROM _7UR_participants_database GROUP BY _7UR_participants_database.coin_id ASC";
                
    $request->execute([]);  // you do not have something like this also i never put value since i don't know what your doing
    $item_info = $request->fetchAll(); // store the fetched on $item_info also you need to indicate what data type you fetching by default it always PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```